# Configure logback-spring.xml to have some common loggers & few environment specific loggers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I was trying to configure logback-spring.xml which will have loggers specific to environment.
This is what I was trying

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern name="basicPattern">My Pattern</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--For Prod envs, only INFO levels are added -->
<springProfile name="prod | staging">
    // Have only loggers with INFO e.g.
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="INFO"/>
</springProfile>

<!-- For all non-prod envs, it'll be DEBUG level -->
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</root>
```

Instead of having 2 or multiple `<springProfiles>` for each environment, how to configure for something specific & rest applicable to all environments?

I've tried this but didn't work. Is there some sequence which matters or do I have to duplicate all logs config in both `<springProfiles>`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You're alreadying doing what you're asking I tihnk. Use profiles for something specific, and the rest for all environments? Or do you mean configuration for all **other** environments?

Comment: @George Couldn't find any spring doc saying that such configuration is possible.
Does the sequence in which configs are written matter? e.g. If I wrote NON-PROD all above & then PROD overrides some specific ones..?

Its all not clear..